# Mass-reversing smartsheet mistake

Tags: smartsheet-api

Someone managed to copy and paste a huge amount of data into the wrong place in smartsheet. Of course it wasn't reversed at the time, and now I have the lovely task of reversing out all of the entries. Manually. One cell at a time.

There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Get Cell History](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-cell-history) endpoint on the Smartsheet API. When you call that you'll get a response back that looks like this:

```
{
  "pageNumber": 1,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalCount": 3,
  "data": [
      {
        "columnId":4567890123456789,
        "displayValue": "Revision 3",
        "columnType": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "value": "Revision 3",
        "modifiedAt": "2013-06-24T00:10:18Z",
        "modifiedBy" : {
            "name" : "Jane Smart",
            "email" : "jane.smart@smartsheet.com"
        }
    },
    {
        "columnId":4567890123456789,
        "displayValue": "Revision 2",
        "columnType": "TEXT_NUMBER",
        "value": "Revision 2",
        "modifiedAt": "2013-06-23T00:10:18Z",
        "modifiedBy" : {
            "name" : "Joe Smart",
            "email" : "joe.smart@smartsheet.com"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

You should be able to write a script that analyzes the revisions and lets you revert the value in a more automated fashion.